# Передать значение переменной ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Проблема - "&mestor=" + mestor,

вроде по документации все верно

```
var btn = document.querySelectorAll("a");
for (var i=0;i<btn.length;i++){
    btn[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        var mesta = this.getAttribute('data');
        var mestor = 0;
        switch (mesta) {
            case "1":
                var mestor = "Шапка сайта";
             break;
            default:
                var mestor = "Не знаю";
        }
    })
}

$("#contactForm").validator().on("submit", function (event) {
    if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        // handle the invalid form...
        formError();
        submitMSG(false, "Пожалуйста заполните все поля");
    } else { 
        // everything looks good!
        event.preventDefault();
        submitForm();
    }
});
function submitForm(){
    // Initiate Variables With Form Content
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var phone = $("#phone").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/form-process.php",
        data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&phone=" + phone + "&mestor=" + mestor,
        success : function(text){
            if (text == "success"){
                formSuccess();
            } else {
                formError();
                submitMSG(false,text);
            }
        }
    });
}

function formSuccess(){
    $("#contactForm")[0].reset();
    submitMSG(true, "Ваша заявка отправлена ! С вами свяжется наш менеджер")
}

function formError(){
    $("#contactForm").removeClass().addClass('shake animated').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
        $(this).removeClass();
    });
}

function submitMSG(valid, msg){
    if(valid){
        var msgClasses = "h3 text-center tada animated text-success";
    } else {
        var msgClasses = "h3 text-center text-danger";
    }
    $("#msgSubmit").removeClass().addClass(msgClasses).text(msg);
}
```

Comment: а вопрос в чем?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman "&mestor=" + mestor, не передается 
https://monosnap.com/file/PiZjHNQ7JDNE1KzokfMPRJhlI00cEC

Comment: код на картинке и в вопросе различаются

Comment: @MikhailVaysman это я уже шаманю и не знаю что делать

Comment: почитайте вот это [ask] и это [tour]

Comment: @MikhailVaysman я не могу понять чем вопрос мой не понятен ? 
Я не могу передать переменную mestor по ajax

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [mcve]

Comment: переменная `mestor` не определена в `submitForm`

Answer (score 0):

У вас проблема с областью видимости с этой переменной, она есть только в функции хендлере клика.

```
var btn = document.querySelectorAll("a");
var mestor = 0;
for (var i=0;i<btn.length;i++){
    btn[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        var mesta = this.getAttribute('data');
        switch (mesta) {
            case "1":
               mestor = "Шапка сайта";
             break;
            default:
               mestor = "Не знаю";
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделай переменную глобальной для всего файла, а дату в запрос передавай через объект так проще:

```
var data = {
    name: $("#name").val();
    email: $("#email").val();
    phone: $("#phone").val();
    mestor: mestor
}
```

І отправяй в запрос

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/form-process.php",
        data: data,
```